# How to conveniently store common logs and client specific logs

Tags: java, logging

I have a huge code base which serves info requests about colleges. There is a base framework code, and we have some separate packages for college1, college2, etc.,

Whenever there is a request for some info about college X, both framework code and college specific code both are triggered. I want to see logs generated for all requests for Company X to go to one location, and company Y to go to one location.

How do I use JUL or apache's logging.properties file to achieve this ? How do I ensure logs written by common framework libraries for company X go to one location, and logs written by common framework libraries for company Y go to some other location ?

Comment: Have you considered logback? It can do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would have an xml file that contain the appenders to specify what packages go into what log file.

You can then load the xml file in your application entry point. Below is an example I have used in my current project

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<!-- appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <param name="threshold" value="error" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] %p %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="codebaseXAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="codebaseX.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] %d %p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="codebaseYAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="codebaseY.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] %d %p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

    <!-- Application logger -->
    <logger name="com.codebasePackageX" additivity="true">
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="codebaseXAppender" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Application logger -->
    <logger name="com.codebasePackageY" additivity="true">
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="codebaseYAppender" />
    </logger>

    </log4j:configuration>
```